# python 2.7.14 & 3.6 good practice for package imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, py2exe

I'm having some trouble with latest python version (2 & 3) to find a good common way for imports.

About the packages I pushed on PyPI, that's ok yet as I create a subfolder for the package, then use `package.module` in `__init__.py` for imports.
I would do the same in module files.

Other than that, I have some packages that I share between projects (stored on my svn server) which I import as svn external in projects.

The hierarchy is usually designed this way:

```
package:
 |- __init__.py
 |- module1.py
 |- module2.py
 |- ...
```

When I import it into projects, folders looks like this:

```
project:
 |- package:
     |- what's above
 |- app.py
```

I usually develop the package itself as a project, meaning `package` is root.
When I import it into projects, they become packages, thus not at root anymore.

When using `package.module` or `.module` in standalone package project, of course, this does not work.
When using same as package in other projects, this tends to work almost fine, but I experience some issues with Python 3.6, telling that some names aren't defined (when launched directly from the command line; but working under pycharm).
Last but not least, when using py2exe to make executables (from Python 2.7), I get some undefined names (classes, etc) exceptions even if imports seems to be ok as no such exception is raised; please note I was able to see that related .pyc files are there in library.zip.

I did not go through these issues some months ago, neither python 2 nor python 3 with older versions.

I open this question as I searched on StackOverflow, python documentation (2 & 3) and a lot through the web these last days without finding something that is really relevant to the overall issue.

My question is, does anyone have any clue on a good practice for imports that would be compatible between python 2 & 3, and which would work also when package is `__main__`? And the bonus, still ok when packed with py2exe?

At some point, i tried some `try/except ImportError` blocks for these imports, but it messes things up a bit & seems to be unreliable.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some clues about `__package__` from:

[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time?rq=1)

I found some more consistent solution to check before import.

```
if __package__ is None or __package__ == '':
    from module1 import *
    from module2 import *
else:
    from .module1 import *
    from .module2 import *
```

In case you run directly from the file itself (let's say `module1`), `__package__` is None. I still had to add check for `__package__ == ''` as if `module1` imports `module2`, package is not `None` in `module2`.

In this case, I prefer using relative imports even if not really recommended, as when used as a package, the package itself can have any name without changing anything.

About `__init__.py` file, I just use relative imports as it will be used only when importing as a package from the main app with:

```
import package
from package import xxx
```

This seems to solve things well about imports for both python 2.7.14 & 3.6, yet still causes issues with py2exe (2.7) and doesn't generate the whole poject.